# Ubuntu Mate 18.04 Mission Control / Activities

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, activities-overview

Does Ubuntu Mate 18.04 have a 'mission control' feature like on Mac? Similar to the Ubuntu 18.04 Activities feature.

If so, what's the shortcut?

Comment: Try to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ to get the answer.